# Under which circumstances does socket.send not send all data?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) of socket.send says:

> Returns the number of bytes sent. Applications are responsible for checking that all data has been sent; if only some of the data was transmitted, the application needs to attempt delivery of the remaining data.

I believe I have observed an instance of this in production. The fix is easy: Use `sendall` instead. However I'm struggling to reproduce the issue for a test.

How can I get `send` to not send all the data passed to it?

I've tried repeatedly writing to a socket that is never read, but it will just fill the buffer and then block.

Comment: Check the last send before the block. Did it send all of the data?

Comment: How about an async socket?